# Joining a series of paths components in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

How do I join a series of path components in common lisp?

In python, I can do,

```
`os.path.join("/home/", username, "dira", "dirb", "dirc");`
```

What would be the equivalent in common lisp?

Of course I can write my own function, but I suspect I should be able to use something built-in.

Comment: Pathnames aren't the same things as strings.  When Common Lisp was created, there was a bit more variety in the way that systems represented paths, so the language has some nice features for manipulating pathnames.  As [Dirk shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24360997/1281433), your task becomes much easier if you use pathnames and the associated functions rather than strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you insist on using strings to represent pathnames, then there seems to be no built-in  solution except rolling your own.

```
(defun join-strings (list &key (separator "/") (force-leading nil))
  (let* ((length (length list))
         (separator-size (length separator))
         (text-size (reduce #'+ (mapcar #'length list) :initial-value 0))
         (size (+ text-size (* separator-size (if force-leading length (1- length)))))
         (buffer (make-string size)))
    (flet ((copy-to (position string)
             (loop
               :with wp := position
               :for char :across string 
               :do (setf (char buffer (prog1 wp (incf wp))) char)
               :finally (return wp))))
      (loop
        :with wp := 0
        :for string :in list
        :do (when (or force-leading (plusp wp)) (setf wp (copy-to wp separator)))
            (setf wp (copy-to wp string)))
      buffer)))

(join-strings '("home" "kurt" "source" "file.txt") :force-leading t)
==> "/home/kurt/source/file.txt"
```

However, if you can use [pathnames](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/19_a.htm), then you could, for example, do:

```
(merge-pathnames #P"subdir1/subdir2/file.type" #P"/usr/share/my-app")
==> #P"/usr/share/my-app/subdir1/subdir2/file.type"
```

The pathname API also provides functions to manipulate pathnames symbolically, extract the components of a pathname, etc.:

```
(pathname-directory #P"subdir1/subdir2/file.type")
==> '(:relative "subdir1" "subdir2")

(pathname-name #P"subdir1/subdir2/file.type")
==> "file"

(pathname-type #P"subdir1/subdir2/file.type")
==> "type"

(make-pathname :name "file" :type "type" :directory '(:relative "subdir1" "subdir2"))
==> #P"subdir1/subdir2/file.type"
```

In particular, the `directory` component of a pathname is represented as a list, and thus, you can use the full set of list handling functions to derive `directory` values from others:

```
(make-pathname :directory (append '(:absolute "usr" "share") '("more" "stuff"))
               :name "packages" :type "lisp")
```

Comment: Note: in merge-pathnames, the presence or absence of a `/` for the subdirectory (first argument) is meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler join-strings

```
(defun join-strings (lst sep)
  (if
   (atom lst)
   lst
   (reduce
    (lambda (a b)
      (concatenate 'string a sep b))
    (cdr lst)
    :initial-value (car lst))))
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using `:from-end T` to avoid quadratic behaviour... but then it probably wouldn't avoid it. with paths it's theoretical, but you did give your function this generic name.....